# time complexity of nested loops - always just a multiplication of each of them seperated?

Tags: c, loops, time-complexity, big-o

When looking at this code for example :

```
for (int i = 1; i < n; i*=2)
  for (int j = 0; j < i; j +=2)
  {
    // some contstant time operations
  }
```

Is it as simple as saying that because the outer loop is log and and inner loop is n , that combined the result is big(O) of nlogn ?

Comment: If n is fixed the compiler can do lot of magic

Comment: No. You have to write down a sum of series and come up with analytical solution

Comment: @Rogue notice it is i *= 2. So i will be 1, 2, 4, 8, ... instead of 1, 2, 3, 4... This should be `log n`.

Comment: In the multiplication of `a * b`, it is equivalent to `a + a + ... + a` a total of `b` times, or `b + b + ... + b` a total of `a` times, so yes this would be roughly equivalent in a truly _linear_ loop. Following the answer below, you can see that we follow a similar reasoning of the inner loop running roughly `n` times (simplifying early!), and the outer loop being `O(log2 n)`, that you would arrive at `O(n log2 n)` (which simplifies further in big-O notation). This would not be a _tight_ bound, since we are simplifying the actual runtime early, but it would still represent a worst-case bound

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the analysis of the example in the question. For simplicity I will neglect the increment of `2` in the inner loop and will consider it as `1`, because in terms of complexity it does not matter - the inner loop is linear in `i` and the constant factor of `2` does not matter.
So we can notice, that the outer loop is producing `i`s of values which are powers of `2` capped by `n`, that is:

```
1, 2, 4, 8, ... , 2^(log2 n)
```

these numbers are also the numbers that the *"constant time operation"* in the inner loop is running for each `i`.
So all we have to do is to sum up the above series. It is easy to see that these are geometric series:

```
2^0 + 2^1 + 2^2 + ... + 2^(log2 n)
```

and it has a well known solution:
[image]

(from [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series) )

We have `a=1`, `r=2`, and... well `n_from_the_image =log n`. We have a same name for different variables here, so it is a bit of a problem.

Now let's substitute and get that the sum equals

```
(1-2^((log2 n) + 1) / (1 - 2) = (1 - 2*n) / (1-2) = 2n-1
```

Which is a linear `O(n)` complexity.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, we take the `O` time complexity to be the **number of times the innermost loop is executed** (and here we assume the innermost loop consists of statements of `O(1)` time complexity).

---

Consider your example. The first loop executes `O(log N)` times, and the second innermost loop executes `O(N)` times. If something `O(N)` is being executed `O(log N)` times, then yes, the final time complexity is just them multiplied: `O(N log N)`.

Generally, this holds true with most nested loops: you can assume their big-O time complexity to be the time complexity of each loop, multiplied.

---

However, there are exceptions to this rule when you can consider the `break` statement. If the loop has the possibility of breaking out early, the time complexity will be different.

Take a look at this example I just came up with:

```
for(int i = 1; i <= n; ++i) {
    int x = i;
    while(true) {
        x = x/2;
        if(x == 0) break;
    }
}
```

Well, the innermost loop is `O(infinity)`, so can we say that the total time complexity is `O(N) * O(infinity) = O(infinity)`? No. In this case we know the innermost loop will always break in `O(log N)`, giving a total `O(N log N)` time complexity.

Comment: Your analysis of the example from the question does not seem correct. The inner loop is executing for *at most* log N times, so the overall complexity can't exceed O( (log n)^2 )

Comment: @EugeneSh. What? But the outer loop is O(N)... You have the series log(1)+log(2)+log(3)...log(n) which is N log N

Comment: See my answer..